# Keep getting this error when importing MySQL to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Can anyone tell me where I screwed up here? I keep getting this error message:

```
--
-- Database: `lehili`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_cb_contact_form`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cb_contact_form` (
  `form_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `form_name` varchar( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `form_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =3;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: Did you try selecting a database using `USE lehili`?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of selecting a database in phpMyAdmin is to click on the database name from the left pan as demonstrated in the following screen shot:

[image]

As shown from your dump code, the database name is a comment for just as reference.

So you have to create an empty new database, if you are not already have one, and import the dump code you have. Don't forget to set suitable collation for the new database, I prefer `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following

1. Create database 'lehili' in phpmyadmin.
2. Select that database (make sure that it has no tables).
3. Click on the 'Import' menu item.
4. Select the file you have to import.

Now you shouldn't be getting any errors

Comment: This worked. I know it probably seemed like a dumb question, but I was trying to import into another database, but it wasn't working. Thank you!